# Import specific data from Excel to make a plot

Tags: plotting, import, excel

I need some help with this: I have imported data from an Excel file and I need to make a contour plot of it. The data are in table-like form. Here is a sample of the first few 'rows':

```
{{{"",  0.4,      0.5,      0.6,     0.7,     0.8,     0.9,     1.}, 
  {0.3, 0.00122,  0.00182,  0.00247, 0.00311, 0.00382, 0.00453, 0.00524}, 
  {0.4, 0.000949, 0.00149,  0.0021,  0.00272, 0.00337, 0.00406, 0.00477}, 
  {0.5, 0.000714, 0.00123,  0.00176, 0.00233, 0.00295, 0.00361, 0.00425}, 
  {0.6, 0.000519, 0.000982, 0.00147, 0.002,   0.00257, 0.00317, 0.00382}, 
...}}
```

In the first row I have values for one metric in each cell, let’s say from 0.2, 0.3,…,1. In the first column I have values for the second metric, with values 0.3,0.4,….1.

The upper corner is blank, if we consider it as table.

I need triplets of numbers created like this: I take a value from the first/main row, a value from the first/main column, and  the value at their intersection. So the first triplet would be `{0.4, 0.3, 0.00122}`...

If I insert the data manually, I get exactly what I want with `ListContourPlot[{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},...]`. But it takes a lot of time and seems rather nonsense!

At a second level, I would like to transpose the axes and make a second contour plot. So the first triplet would now be `{0.3, 0.4, 0.00122}` etc.

Since I’m new to *Mathematica* and with no knowledge of programming I am not sure how to get what I want. Some attempts I made were in vain.

Comment: Hi Nik. Have you managed to import your data from Excel yet? If you have, you should add a few rows of the resulting list to your question, then specify which elements you want to be plotted

Comment: Unfortunately not. The point is that my "low reputation" won't let me upload a picture to make my question more specific. If anyone is willing, I will gladly send a personal mail with an excel and a mathematica file attached...

Comment: You should be able to upload code/error messages tho..?

Comment: @cormullion: Let's assume I keep only the data I need for the plot, erase everything else and Import the remaining in mathematica. What I get with Import looks like this:  {{{"", 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}, {0.3, 0.00122, 0.00182, 
   0.00247, 0.00311, 0.00382, 0.00453, 0.00524}, {0.4, 0.000949, 
   0.00149, 0.0021, 0.00272, 0.00337, 0.00406, 0.00477}, {0.5, 
   0.000714, 0.00123, 0.00176, 0.00233, 0.00295, 0.00361, 
   0.00425}, {0.6, 0.000519, 0.000982, 0.00147, 0.002, 0.00257, 
   0.00317, 0.00382}, ... }}. So how I take the triplets next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to propose this, which is similar to Mr.Wizard's answer, but using a simple table rather than rules. I've already removed the outer braces from `data`:

```
dimensions = Dimensions[data]
```

> {5, 8}

```
triplets = Flatten[
   Table[
    {
     data[[1, column]],
     data[[row, 1]],
     data[[row, column]]
     },
    {row, 2, First[dimensions]},
    {column, 2, Last[dimensions]}] , 1];

ListContourPlot[triplets, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]
```

[image: gratuitous plot]

Comment: Works for me. +1

Answer (score 4):

Starting with your data as given:

```
tbl = {{{"", 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}, {0.3, 0.00122, 0.00182, 0.00247, 0.00311, 
     0.00382, 0.00453, 0.00524}, {0.4, 0.000949, 0.00149, 0.0021, 0.00272, 0.00337, 
     0.00406, 0.00477}, {0.5, 0.000714, 0.00123, 0.00176, 0.00233, 0.00295, 0.00361, 
     0.00425}, {0.6, 0.000519, 0.000982, 0.00147, 0.002, 0.00257, 0.00317, 0.00382}}};
```

We might first strip the outer level of brackets, then extract three sections to work with:

```
tbl = First @ tbl;

row = tbl[[1, 2 ;;]]
col = tbl[[2 ;;, 1]]
tbl2 = tbl[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}
>
> {0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6}
>
> {{0.00122, 0.00182, 0.00247, 0.00311, 0.00382, 0.00453, 0.00524},
>  {0.000949, 0.00149, 0.0021, 0.00272, 0.00337, 0.00406, 0.00477},
>  {0.000714, 0.00123, 0.00176, 0.00233, 0.00295, 0.00361, 0.00425},
>  {0.000519, 0.000982, 0.00147, 0.002, 0.00257, 0.00317, 0.00382}}
> ```

Now we can get your triplets with any one of these lines:

```
dat = Most @ ArrayRules @ tbl2 /. ({c_, r_} -> val_) :> {row[[r]], col[[c]], val}

dat = Join @@ MapIndexed[{row[[Last @ #2]], col[[First @ #2]], #} &, tbl2, {2}]

dat = {row[[Last @ #]], col[[First @ #]], #2} & @@@ Most @ ArrayRules @ tbl2

dat = {#[[2]], #[[1]], #2} & @@@ Thread[{Tuples @ {col, row}, Join @@ tbl2}]

dat = Join @@ Array[{row[[#2]], col[[#]], tbl2[[##]]} &, Dimensions @ tbl2]

(* from Simon Woods; I wish I'd thought of this! *)
dat = Join[Tuples@{row, col}, {tbl2} ~Flatten~ {3, 2}, 2]
```

And plot them:

```
ListContourPlot[dat]
```

[image]

Or in one expression (after `tbl = First @ tbl;`):

```
ListContourPlot[
 {tbl[[1, 1 + Last@#]], tbl[[1 + First@#, 1]], #2} & @@@ Most@ArrayRules@tbl[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
]
```

And here cormullion's method in my terse style:

```
ListContourPlot[
  Array[
    {tbl[[1, #2]], tbl[[#, 1]], tbl[[##]]} &,
    Dimensions[tbl] - 1, 2
  ] ~Flatten~ 1
]
```

Comment: +1 A good introduction to the power of Mathematica for the OP! :)

Comment: @cormullion Thanks.  I added a third flavor; hopefully he likes one of them.  Yours is very nice, and probably easier to understand for someone coming from a different language.

Comment: I wonder how long ago it was since you were a beginning wizard (sorcerer's apprentice) -  you're scarily good sometimes...:)

Comment: @cormullion It's been over twelve years since my introduction, but it seems like a lot less.

Comment: @  Mr.Wizard @cormullion Thank you for your time and effort! Your methods are excellent! My answer will be actually marked “checked” afterwards! I get the result I need. But I’d like something more: in some cases, I’d like the order of triplets changed, e.g. instead {0.4,0.3,0.00122}, I need {0.3,0.4,0.00122}  .This would interchange the axes  in the contourplot. How I can get that, either by changing the order of triplets, or by interchanging the axes directly on the plot? If you like, please provide some more information about what each command does, so as to try it on my own in the future!

Comment: @NikGkav In the case of the simple solution (mine), you should change the order of the first two lines inside the 'triplet construction list' in the `Table` function (i.e. the `data[[1, column]]` and `data[[row, 1]]`. `Table` should be one of the first Mathematica  functions you study...  For Mr.Wizard' answers, you can just flip the table (`tbl = Transpose[tbl]`) just after `tbl = First@tbl;` (I think...)

Comment: @cormullion, @ Mr.Wizard thank you very much for your interest and time! A work nicely done!

Comment: @Simon Woods,cormullion, Mr.Wizard : it is a pity I cannot accept all your 3 answers at the same time!

Comment: Also `dat = Join[Tuples@{row, col}, {tbl2}~Flatten~{{3, 2}}, 2]`

Comment: @Simon we should write each other's answers; we seem to be pretty good at it. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since the x and y values are evenly spaced, I will mention that another option is to give `ListContourPlot` just the data array rather than a list of triplets, and use the `DataRange` option to specify the ranges of the axes.

Starting from Mr Wizard's `row`, `col` and `tbl2`:

```
ListContourPlot[tbl2, DataRange -> {row[[{1, -1}]], col[[{1, -1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Simon Woods:Thanks, too, for your answer! Equally excellent! What does {row[[{1, -1}]], col[[{1, -1}]]} performs? (begginner's ignorance). The same request for you how: can I change the order of triplets, or equivalently, interchange the axes in the final plot?

Comment: @NikGkav, `row[[{1,-1}]]` gives a list containing the first and last elements of `row`. It's the same as `{First[row], Last[row]}`. To interchange the axes you will need to transpose the data array and also swap `row` for `col` in the `DataRange`, so it would be `ListContourPlot[Transpose[tbl2], DataRange -> {col[[{1, -1}]], row[[{1, -1}]]}]`

Comment: @ Simon Woods: thanks a lot for the clarification and answer as a whole!

Comment: Somewhat shorter: `ListContourPlot[tbl2, DataRange -> {row, col}[[All, {1, -1}]]]` (BTW, nice answer.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, nice one, shorter and I think more readable too.