# How can I divide y-axis by a number in ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to divide y-axis by 300, so I used below code but it didn't work.

```
dpg3 = ListContourPlot[ddatas1r, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Black, BaseStyle -> Thick,DataRange -> {xrange, yrange}]
```

Comment: You meant to say that divide each point on $y$-axis by 300?

Comment: Yes,exactly @MMM

Comment: Have a look at `Ticks`.

Comment: As @MMM said, I want to divide each point on y-axis by 300

Comment: It's easier to scale the y values by 300 than it is to scale the ticks I think, `ListContourPlot[{#1, #2/300, #3} & @@@ ddatas1r, 
 ContourShading -> False, Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick]`

Comment: @JasonB. Your approach just scale down $y-axis$, where as Alan's method along with scale down also change the out look of the graph.  Why is that?

Comment: When Alan posted his answer, OP had not included enough code to generate the data, so he had to make up some data to show how to do it.  There has to be a duplicate for this question.

Comment: possible dupe: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55889/9490

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
xrange = {1, Length[data[[1]]]}
yrange = {1, Length[data]}/300;
dpg1 = ListContourPlot[data, ContourShading -> False, 
  Contours -> {0},
  DataRange -> {xrange, yrange}]
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code doesn't work in my case :( I added the code to the question

Comment: @saranj - that's because you defined your data as a list of `{x, y, z}` values, so the data range is set by the list itself.  I prefer Alan's method myself, keep the data as an array of z values, and supply the data range.  in your case the data to plot would be `ddatas1rArray = Table[ds1r, {e, 4000, 30000, 500}, {v, 0, 40, 3}]` and the `DataRange` would be `{{0, 39}, {4000, 30000}/300}`